# Detectar cierre window

Tags: javascript, html

Saludos deseo detectar el cierre de una ventana que abro mediante el evento click, tengo el siguiente código:

**html:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="btnGoogleMaps">
  <i class="fa fa-map-marked" ></i> GoogleMaps
</a>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementById("btnGoogleMaps").addEventListener("click",function(e){
  var miModal = window.open('https://www.google.com/maps','xtf','900','500');
},false);
```

La ventana la abre de forma correcta pero la idea es detectar el cierre de esta y obtener/capturar la URL de dicha ventana antes del cierre.

tengo entendido que con esto:

```
miModal.onunload = function(){
    alert('cerrado');
};
```

se puede obtener el evento del cierre pero al momento de colocarlo me dice por consola "miModal undefined" y debo suponer que es porque la misma se crea dentro del evento click y mas no afuera de este.

Como puedo controlar esto gracias de antemano..!!

Comment: Definí `var miModal = null;` afuera de la función y dentro `miModal = windows.open();`, de esa forma vas a poder usar `miModal` por fuera. Ahora, dudo que puedas saber si se cerró una ventana que tiene una URL distinta a la tuya.

Comment: declara la variable `miModal` fuera del evento y inicializala dentro.